# How to fix Unsupported Media Type in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core-webapi

I use EF to create WebAPi. Everything seems fine. I add Swagger into the app.
I login user from Xamarin Forms sang ASP.NET Identity using OAuth.

```
public async Task LoginAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("phoneNum", userName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("passwordUs", password),
        };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Post, "https://xxxxxxx/api/Token");

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine(content);
    }
```

However, I get the error: `Unsupported Media Type`. Meanwhile I checked on Swagger, Ok

[image]

Please help me with the solution. Thanks

**Update**
I've added:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

I checked on Swagger and Postman both ok

[image]

However, I get the error: `Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: API expects JSON yet you are sending form data. Send the supported content type (application/json) and that should solve your problem.

Comment: I've added: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); However when debugging I still get the above error

Comment: Can you help me by being more clear in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Curl and Postman in the shown images, the API most likely expects JSON yet the shown code is sending URL encoded form data.

```
//...

request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

//...
```

Send the supported content type (application/json) and that should solve your problem.

For example

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task LoginAsync(string userName, string password) {
    var model = new {
        phoneNum = userName,
        passwordUs = password
    };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    string url = "https://xxxxxxx/api/Token";

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Debug.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
```

The above refactoring of the original code creates a model with the desired members and serializes it to JSON using [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

That content is what will be posted to the API as the request body in the expected format.